# Using Powershell to call an .NET DLL's Static Method which Spawns Multiple Threads

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, powershell, dll

Problem:

I am trying to write a Powershell script that will execute a static method in a DLL that was written in .NET.  I am able to execute the method, but Powershell closes almost immediately after a successful execution of the method.

I believe that this is due to the fact that the particular method I am executing spawns new threads to perform some asynchronous actions?

I have tested to see if the additional threads get spun up in the originating Powershell session, and they do.  Since this is the case, my thoughts are, Powershell should be keeping track of any thread spawned by the DLL, and should wait until the process is completed.

I am new to scripting in Powershell, and may be missing something.  I have been grinding my gears for a while now, and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Below is a sample of my code:

```
[string]$DLLPathStr = ("C:\test.dll");
Add-Type -Path $DLLPathStr;
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile($DLLPathStr);
[Namespace.Class]::StaticMethod(10); #Spawns Ten Send Email Processes.
```

Additional Information:

The Class being used in the DLL to create threads is Thread/ Threadstart.

Example of .NET Code:

```
    public int Foo()
{
 ThreadStart ts = new ThreadStart(Bar);
 Thread wt = new Thread(ts);
 wt.Start();
 return 1;
}
private void Bar()
{
 //...do something that takes a minute or two...
}
```

Powershell Version Table:

PSVersion                      4.0
WSManStackVersion              3.0
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
BuildVersion                   6.3.9600.16406
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.2

Comment: Forget about PowerShell for a moment. If I were calling this method from a C# program, how would I know that it has completed and I can close my program?

Comment: The .NET environment waits to complete all threads spawned by the called method before closing (for example, a .NET console application that does nothing but call this method does not close the console until the asynchronous method completes, even if it takes, say, 20 minutes).

Comment: My PowerShell script calls a static method in a .NET assembly. That assembly method calls a separate, asynchronous method (also within the assembly). After triggering the start of the asynchronous method, the first method returns a value to my script. The asynchronous method is still running, but since my script sees a return value, it assumes everything is complete and closes the Powershell instance. Is there a way to make sure that the asynchronous method finishes prior to Powershell closing if that asynchronous method doesn't return a value directly to my script?

Comment: Right .NET prevents the application from closing, but does not prevent further calls from being processed after your call returns. PowerShell will exit itself when the command pipeline is empty unless you have provided the NoExit flag at the command line. You need a mechanism for the caller to know when the operation is complete. That way your script can wait until the operation is done.

Comment: I agree, but lets assume that the .NET code cannot be modified.  Powershell is getting a return, and then closes.  How would you force Powershell to wait until the threads that were spawned finished processing?